# json помогите вытащить данные

Tags: python, json

как вытащить `name` зная только `code`

```
{
    "time_zone": "America/Lima",
    "name": "Андауайлас",
    "flightable": true,
    "coordinates": {
      "lon": -73.355835,
      "lat": -13.716667
    },
    "code": "ANS",
    "name_translations": {
      "en": "Andahuaylas"
    },
    "country_code": "PE",
    "city_code": "ANS"
  },
  {
    "time_zone": "Asia/Shanghai",
    "name": "Линьфэнь",
    "flightable": true,
    "coordinates": {
      "lon": 111.64158,
      "lat": 36.13222
    },
    "code": "LFQ",
    "name_translations": {
      "en": "Linfen Qiaoli Airport"
    },
    "country_code": "CN",
    "city_code": "LFQ"
  },
  {
    "time_zone": "Europe/Saratov",
    "name": "Гагарин",
    "flightable": true,
    "coordinates": {
      "lon": 46.166667,
      "lat": 51.716667
    },
    "code": "GSV",
    "name_translations": {
      "en": "Saratov Gagarin Airport"
    },
    "country_code": "RU",
    "city_code": "RTW"
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала распарсите `json` с помощью одноимённого модуля, а затем отфильтруйте элементы любым удобным образом.

Я воспользовался функцией `filter`, передав её следующую `lambda`:

```py
lambda x: x['code'] == CODE
```

***Пример:***

```py
import json


def main():
    json_string = r'[{"time_zone":"America/Lima","name":"Андауайлас","flightable":true,"coordinates":{"lon":-73.355835,"lat":-13.716667},"code":"ANS","name_translations":{"en":"Andahuaylas"},"country_code":"PE","city_code":"ANS"},{"time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","name":"Линьфэнь","flightable":true,"coordinates":{"lon":111.64158,"lat":36.13222},"code":"LFQ","name_translations":{"en":"Linfen Qiaoli Airport"},"country_code":"CN","city_code":"LFQ"},{"time_zone":"Europe/Saratov","name":"Гагарин","flightable":true,"coordinates":{"lon":46.166667,"lat":51.716667},"code":"GSV","name_translations":{"en":"Saratov Gagarin Airport"},"country_code":"RU","city_code":"RTW"}]'
    d = json.loads(json_string)

    CODE = 'LFQ'
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x['code'] == CODE, d))[0]['name']
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
Линьфэнь
```